# findById(req.params.id) returns null as response?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

My issue is different than others, when I passed /:id then I return JSON yeah its ok, but issue is that when I give wrong objectId it return null value with statusCode 200 instead of error that this id is wrong. according to my perception it call .catch block instead of .then block because id is not available on database.

```
const get_id_docs = async (req, res) => {
    await models
        .findById(req.params.id)
        .then(result => {
            res.send(result)
            })
        .catch(err => {
            res.sendStatus(404).send("Link Not Found")
        })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases, one an invalid id,  and the other a valid id but doesn't exists in db.

If you want to differentiate an invalid id, you can validate it before querying, and return 404.

Also you mixed async await and Promise, one of them must be used in this case.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const get_id_docs = async (req, res) => {
  const isValidId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id);

  if (!isValidId) {
    res.status(404).send("Link Not Found - invalid id");
  }

  try {
    const result = await models.findById(req.params.id);
    if (result) {
      res.send(result);
    }
    res.status(404).send("Link Not Found - does not exists");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
};
```

And if you prefer then catch

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const get_id_docs = (req, res) => {
  const isValidId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id);

  if (!isValidId) {
    res.status(404).send("Link Not Found - invalid id");
  }

 models.findById(req.params.id).then(result => {
         if (result) {
             res.send(result);
          }
          res.status(404).send("Link Not Found - does not exists");
     })
    .catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
     }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I use `then() catch()` instead of `async-await` because I like to code `then catch` way. and if I use .then then its also necessary to use `async` keyword in function starts?

Answer (score 0):

You are composing various general-purpose libraries that fill a variety of use cases. In particular, database abstraction frameworks typically try to percent a collection like facade over the underlying data stores. In JavaScript, methods like `Array.prototype.find` return `undefined` rather than throwing errors. And I think the authors of mongoose are trying to write analogously behaving APIs.

In addition to providing intuitive default Behavior, by not throwing errors, this enable a wider range of use cases, such as checking for existence, to be handled without boilerplate.

Given that, you want something like the following

```
const get_id_docs = async (req, res) => {
    const result = await models.findById(req.params.id);
    if (result) {
        res.send(result);
    } 
    res.sendStatus(404).send("Link Not Found");    
 };
```

Note that the above has other advantages including that it does not propagate other kinds of errors as 404s arbitrarily.